# Not able to display image from API's URL in Angular dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular

as i said in title, i'm using free api for displaying crypto currency news for my practice project. Seems like everything is fine except displaying the images in card view.
I will post here my code, so if you have any idea how to fix, please help me.

From the app service:

```
 getNews(): Observable<any> {
return this._http.get("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/?lang=EN")
  .map(result => this.result = result)
  .pipe(catchError(this.handleError('getPriceSingle', [])));
```

}
Controller:

```
this._data.getNews()
    .subscribe(res => {
    this.receiveData = res.Data 
    let newsObj: any = Object.keys(this.receiveData);
    let newsValues: any = Object.values(this.receiveData);

    for (let i = 0; i < newsValues.length; i++) {
      this.newsX[newsValues[i]] = {
        title: newsValues[i].title,
        url: newsValues[i].url,
        body: newsValues[i].body,
        image: newsValues[i].imageurl,
        date: newsValues[i].published_on,
        tags: newsValues[i].tags
      };
    }

    this.newsData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Object.values(newsValues)));
    console.log(this.newsData)
});
```

And view:

```
<nz-layout>
<nz-content>
  <header>
    <h1>Latest Crypto Currency News</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="band">
    <div class="item-7" *ngFor="let news of newsData">
      <a href="{{news.url}}" class="card">
        <div class="thumb">
          <img [src]='news.image' />
        </div>
        <article>
          <h1>{{news.title}}</h1>
          <span>Release Date: {{today | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
        </article>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
    </nz-content>
```

Comment: can you share the result of the console.log(this.newsData) please

Comment: {
    "id": "26935554",
    "guid": "https://ambcrypto.com/?p=149399",
    "published_on": 1616587240,
    "imageurl": "https://images.cryptocompare.com/news/default/ambcrypto.png",
    "title": "Genesis Shards raises $2.7M to create new pre-IDO market using DeFi NFT options",
    "url": "https://ambcrypto.com/genesis-shards-raises-2-7m-to-create-new-pre-ido-market-using-defi-nft-options/",
    "tags": "HideCryptopanic|PR|Press Release",
    "categories": "Market|ICO|Sponsored",
    "upvotes": "0",
    "downvotes": "0",
    "lang": "EN",
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing what you're trying to accomplish, I'd say the back and forth conversions using `Object.keys` and `Object.values` aren't required here. Try the following

1. Avoid the subscription in the controller. Use Angular `async` pipe instead. This also avoids potential memory leaks due to open subscriptions.
2. Use RxJS `map` operator along with JS `Array#map` function to transform the data as per your requirement.
3. This is more of a subjective semantic opinion. While binding variables in the template, using the same quotes across all the bindings is more elegant compared to using double for few and single for others like you're doing.

**Controller**

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({ ... })
export class NzDemoLayoutFixedComponent {
  newsData$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newsData$ = this._data.getNews().pipe(
      map((res: any) =>
        res["Data"].map(item => ({
          title: item["title"],
          url: item["url"],
          body: item["body"],
          image: item["imageurl"],
          date: new Date(item["published_on"] * 1000), // credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/847196/6513921
          tags: item["tags"]
        }))
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**Template**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(newsData$ | async) as newsData">
  <nz-layout class="layout">
    <nz-content style="padding:0 50px;margin-top:64px;">
      <header>
        <h1>Latest Crypto Currency News</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="band">
        <div class="item-7" *ngFor="let news of newsData">
          <a [href]="news.url" class="card">
            <div class="thumb">
              <img [src]="news.image" />
            </div>
            <article>
              <h1>{{ news.title }}</h1>
              <span>Release Date: {{ news.date | date: "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm" }}</span>
            </article>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nz-content>
  </nz-layout>
</ng-container>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-layout-fixed-r2pq8r?file=src/app/app.component.ts)